# How to access function from another script without causing Attribute error

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 2 scripts: mainmenu.py and join.py; the former gathers an input string from the user and have it displayed in a **Label** in the latter when button is pressed.

Mainmenu.py:

```
try:

    if __name__ == "__main__":
    
        .......

        def joinlobby(): #function to open join.py when button is pressed

            if (e2.index("end") == 0): #check if entry is blank

                tk.messagebox.showwarning("Fill the info!")

            else:
           
                master.withdraw()
                subprocess.call([sys.executable, "join.py"])

        def getvalueoflist():

            return e2.get()
    
        e2 = tk.Entry(frame3)
        e2.insert(0, "Enter your name")
        e2.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        b4 = tk.Button(frame3, text = "Join", 
         bg = "Black", fg = "White", command = lambda: joinlobby())
        b4.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
```

Join.py

```
import mainmenu

class GUI:

  def __init__(self):

        .......

        self.lname = tk.Label(self.lnameframe, text = mainmenu.getvalueoflist(), 
        font = ("Times New Roman", 15), fg = "Black")
        self.lname.pack(fill = "both")
```

Error:

```
File "join.py", line 32 in __init__
self.lname = tk.Label(self.lnameframe, text = mainmenu.getvalueoflist(), 
        font = ("Times New Roman", 15), fg = "Black")
    self.lname.pack(fill = "both")
AttributeError: module 'mainmenu' has no attribute 'getvalueoflist'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please fix code indention. Right now ti looks like `def getvalueoflist` is inside another function.

Comment: Please, fix the indentation, It looks like you define the function inside `if __name__ =='__main__':` block and probably as nested function as well.

Comment: @mx0 I apologize. I have indented the code.

Comment: If you're going to be using those function as imports, then they cannot be inside an `if __name__` block.  The whole purpose of that section is to have stuff that will not be imported.

Comment: But even above that, your `getvalueoflist` is trying to return `e2`, so if `e2` is created in the `if __name__` block, it will not exist.  It's not at all clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yeah, I apologize for the confusion. The reason I put     if ___name__ is because mainmenu.py was being executed when being imported by join.py. Turns out it caused more problems.

I only want the entry widget value from mainmenu.py to be passed and used as text value of the label widget in john.py.

Comment: OK, but then who's in charge?  Which is the main program?  Who creates the main window?  How can `mainmenu` create widgets if it doesn't have the main window?  Perhaps the "main" code you have in `mainmenu` ALL needs to be in a function that you call, into which you pass the main window instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of `mainmenu.py` has this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
```

It's also all inside a `try ..` block, which seems like not a great idea, but that doesn't affect the problem you're asking about.

The code after the `if __name__ == "__main__":` will only get executed if `__name__` equals `'__main__'`, which is to say, when the `mainmenu.py` file is executed independently.

So, the functions you define in that block, only get defined if `mainmenu.py` is executed directly as the main module.

But when you `import mainmenu`, that doesn't happen. It's loaded as a module, not as the main module, and so the function does not get defined and you get that error.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; guess my coding is causing more problems. As explained in a comment above, I only wanted the entry widget value from mainmenu.py to be passed and used as text value of the label widget in john.py.

I put if __name__ because the whole mainmenu.py was being executed when imported.